# Get 404 when refresh page after using PathLocationStrategy in Angular 7

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

We use angular 7 + node 8.11.4, previously, we use `HashLocationStrategy` and all routes worked, while, as you know, '#' will auto added in URL as Hash flag, now we want to remove '#',  so i use `PathLocationStrategy` instead Hash*. While after changing, when i refresh page, i will get 404 page and it also occur when visit redirect pages, that's my question.

I have searched and known that after changing to `PathLocationStrategy`, all router need to redirect to index.html(default home page), while i'm not sure how to implement it in node environment(most is apache, nginx,tomcat)

See my below code:

**app.module.ts**:

```
providers: [{ provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: PathLocationStrategy }, LookupPsmService, ComponentMapping,
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: PsmHttpInterceptor,
      multi: true
    }, CookieService, AuthGuard],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {CKEditorModule}
```

**index.html**:

```html
<base href="/">
```

**AppRoutingModule**:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

My expected results is remove '#' in URL and can refresh in browser.

Comment: you need to implement URL rewrites on the server.  Without the hash, the server has no idea how to resolve your URL - hence the 404s

Comment: @pixelbits the problem is how to rewrite URL in node... it's confused me

Comment: this might help: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-urlrewrite

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove this to see if it work

```
{ provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: PathLocationStrategy }
```

I dont think you gonna need that

Update to handle 404 in nodejs using express you can do like this

```
app.get('*', function(req, res) ...
```

Comment: Yes, without `LocationStrategy`, it can works while 404 error still exists as before.

Comment: ...emmm not, what i want is to fix 404 bug, do you have any idea in node?

Comment: @KDFinal check my answer again maybe you need to use express in this case

Comment: I refer to an answer in another question, but it doesn't works. 
See code below:

```ts
app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index', {req, res});
});
```